# Return 2 columns, Id and count, from EF as Dictionary<int,int>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an FK relationship between two tables, but for the purpose of this query, I need to get a count of rows for each FK.

For example, I have a `CareTaker` table With `CareTakerId` as PK; and an `Animal` table with `CareTakerId` as FK. Given a list of `CareTakerIds`, I want All AnimalIds that each care taker is responsible for. Something like this:

```
select CareTakerId, count(1) 
from Animal
where CareTakerId in (1,2,3,4)
    and AnimalTypeId = 3
group by CareTakerId
```

Which returns

```
CareTakerId | No ColumnName
1           | 42
2           | 6
```

How do I do this in EntityFramework? 
I need this result, so I thought I'd do it as a `Dictionary<int,int>` (`Dictionary<CareTakerId,Count>`) - but  I cannot figure out how to write the EF query for it.. Here's what I have so far:

```
query
    .Where(r => r.AnimalTypeId == animalTypeId 
             && careTakerIds.Contains(r => r.CareTakerId))
    .GroupBy(r => r.CareTakerId)
    // Not sure what to write here; r.CareTakerId doesn't exist
    .Select(r => new {r.key, r.value }) 
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.value);
```

How do I select `CareTakerId` and count(1) in entity framework please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You was very close, simply add the "Count()" method.

```
query
    .Where(r => r.AnimalTypeId == animalTypeId 
             && careTakerIds.Contains(r => r.CareTakerId))
    .GroupBy(r => r.CareTakerId)
    .Select(r => new {r.key, value = r.Count() }) 
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.value);
```

Answer (score 6):

Do this in your `Select`:

```
//...
//You have groups here, 
//so you can call Count extension method to get how many elements belong to the current group
.Select(g => new {CareTakerId=g.Key,Count= g.Count() })
.ToDictionary(e=> e.CareTakerId,e=> e.Count);
```